# order results from wildcard search according to where matched

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to order text searches according to where they were found in the string.  Those matches that were found at the beginning of the string appear first and so on.  If my description is not clear maybe what I have attempted so far will help.

```
    Select "BANK", "ACH" from "FI" where "ACH" like '1119%'
    Union All
    Select "BANK", "ACH" from "FI" where "ACH" like '%1119%'
```

This is the best I can come up with so far. My gut says it may not be to efficient, and it really does not solve the problem like I thought it might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Select "BANK", "ACH"
from "FI"
where "ACH" like '%1119%'
order by (case when "ACH" like '1119%' then 1 else 2 end);
```

Or, here is another way that is simpler:

```
order by position('1119' in "ACH")
```

This orders by the position of the string you are searching for.

Comment: Great Thank You!  I think the position function really meets the need the best.   I ended up with ORDER BY position('1119' in "LACH"), "LACH"